# PHP - if statement - with - if isset - using multiple variables issue

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, isset

I am having a problem of syntax my code correctly and i would like some help. I would like to use an if statement and  if isset with multiple variables. My existing code is this.

```
$album_name = $_POST['album_name'];
$img = $_POST['image'];
$artist = $_POST['artist'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$genre = $_POST['genre'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$buy_now = $_POST['buy_now'];

if($album_name !='') && if (isset($artist, $company, $price, $buy_now)){
    $sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO top_albums_info (album_name, image, artist,company,genre,price,buy_now) VALUES ('$album_name','$img','$artist','$company','$genre','$price','".$buy_now."') ");
    echo'<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=../index.php?page=top_section&action=list">';
}else{
    echo'<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=../index.php?page=top_section&action=add&msg=empty">';
}

?>
```

How can i combine them?

Thanks.

Comment: It's too late to use isset there.  The variables HAVE BEEN set earlier.  Where you REALLY want isset is `$img = (isset($_POST['image'])) ? $_POST['image'] : '';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
if($album_name !='') && if (isset($artist, $company, $price, $buy_now)){
```

to

```
if ($album_name!='' && isset($artist, $company, $price, $buy_now)) {
```

Comment: isset() also checks for null. But if the sending form always sends those fields, `!empty()` should be used.

Comment: My point is that the code will throw all sorts of notices if the $_POST variables aren't set.

Comment: You **did not** address the issue with PHP notices that will be thrown on the lines like `$albumname = $_POST['albumname'];`

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I handle form submissions completely differently.

BUT, given the structure you have provided, I would recommend doing things a bit differently for ease:

```
// create a list of fields to check in an array
$fields = array(
    'album_name',
    'image',
    'artist',
    'company',
    'price',
    'buy_now'
);

// iterate over the fields defined in your array
foreach ($fields AS $field) {
    // assign the value to the variable ONLY IF the $_POST is set, otherwise empty string
    ${$field} = (isset($_POST[$field])) ? $_POST[$field] : '';
}

// Now you KNOW its set, so you just check if the field "is"
if ($album_name && $image && $artist && $company && $price && $buy_now) {
    // Do stuff.  Form submitted and complete
} else {
    // Do other stuff.  Form not submitted or incomplete
}

When you write `if ($album)`, it's essentially the same as `if ($album != '')`
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the line to

```
if (isset($artist, $company, $price, $buy_now)){
if($album_name !=''){
}
}
```

This will work for sure

Answer (score 2):

Try to use like:

```
$album_name = $_POST['album_name'];
$img = $_POST['image'];
$artist = $_POST['artist'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$genre = $_POST['genre'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$buy_now = $_POST['buy_now'];

if(!empty($album_name) && isset($album_name,$artist,$company,$price,$buy_now)){
    $sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO top_albums_info (album_name, image, artist,company,genre,price,buy_now) VALUES ('$album_name','$img','$artist','$company','$genre','$price','".$buy_now."') ");
echo'<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=../index.php?page=top_section&action=list">';
}else{
    echo'<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=../index.php?page=top_section&action=add&msg=empty">';
}
```

For more detail about `isset()`:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php